# How to move a layout in android studio with views inside? I keep selecting the views inside

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have two linear layouts in a single linear layout and I am having a problem that whenever I try to move the layout, I choose the views inside. this is a really silly but annoying thing. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just move it using the xml code instead of using the design mode to move it. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I was just starting out at that time. Just re-logged in.